# How to use parent and child Constructors in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to understand why and when we use constructors in Javascript.
I was wondering when and how we need to use the constructor of a child and when the parents. Based on my tests there is NO difference when I set the child constructor to itself or to the parent.Lets take a look at the below code :

```
function Mammal(name) {
    this.name = "###"+name;
}
    Cat.prototype = new Mammal();        // Here's where the inheritance occurs 
    Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;       // Otherwise instances of Cat would have a    

function Cat(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Now lets instantiate the Cat and Mamal class and see the name:

```
var mycat = new Cat('Felix');
Alert(mycat.name);         //OUTPUT : "Felix"
```

Now i want to set the constructor of Cat class to the Mamal. To do so I remove the below line

```
//Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat; -->Now the cat Constructor is set to its default(Mamal)
```

**Now I expect that when I call mycat.name, it uses the Mamal constructor and alert "###Felix"
BUT it doesn't. It shows exactly same as the previous result "Felix".**

```
var mycat = new Cat('Felix');
Alert(mycat.name);         //Again OUTPUT is : "Felix" !! but I expected "###Felix"
```

So, why? And can you give me an example of a correct use of constructors in Javascript and when they are important?

Comment: Step 1 - get traceur. Step 2, use ES6 classes, if you really need to. Emulating classes in es5 is cumbersome, that's why they added all the sugar for you in es6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully an examination of how this code runs should clear things up:

```
function Mammal(name) {
    this.name = "###" + name;
}
function Cat(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Cat.prototype = new Mammal();
// omitted change of Cat.prototype.constructor

var felix = new Cat("Felix");
console.log(felix);
```

After defining the first two functions, we create a new `Mammal`, passing it a name of `undefined`, and putting the result into `Cat.prototype`. Now `Cat.prototype` is a `Mammal` with a `name` of `###undefined`.

Then we create a new `Cat`, giving the `Cat` function a name of `Felix`. This `Cat` function sets its `name` property to `Felix`. The `Cat` function completes and `felix` contains a `Cat` object with a `name` of `Felix`.

So why didn’t the `Mammal` function run? Well, it did, but only once when setting up inheritance. If you want the superclass’s constructor to run as part of the subclass’s initialization, you have to do that explicitly:

```
function Cat(name) {
    Mammal.call(this, name);
    this.name = name;
}
```

Of course, you’d still get the same result, because you’d have the `Mammal` function set the `name` property and then `Cat` would write over it again. You could swap it around, too, so the `Mammal` overwrites what `Cat` did:

```
function Cat(name) {
    this.name = name;
    Mammal.call(this, name);
}
```

But then the `Cat` line of `this.name = name;` is useless and you might as well remove it.

So why didn’t your `constructor` change do anything? Because that’s not what `constructor` does. In fact, reading through the ES5 specification, I didn’t see the `constructor` property actually being used for anything at all. Changing `constructor` doesn’t do anything, so that’s why it didn’t matter.

Comment: Exactly. This was my question too. Constructors in ES5 is useless and practically it doesn't do anything special!